Debugging kernel configuration process in Yocto
I am building my own Linux distro using yocto. I'm using ONL linux kernel. I am using few non-standard kernel options using KERNEL_FEATURES, i.e. SCC files + CFG files. It works ok. However, recently I needed to include CONFIG_KEXEC option to the list, and it doesn't get included into resulting .config file. It seems it is being silently ignored. Is there any way I can change the default behavior, and make bitbake quit if config contains options that cannot be included (as opposed to ignoring them) ?
myfeats.scc:
define KFEATURE_DESCRIPTION "Enable my kernel feature."
define KFEATURE_COMPATIBILITY board

kconf non-hardware myfeats.cfg

myfeats.cfg:
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
CONFIG_RD_GZIP=y
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_GZIP=y
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y
CONFIG_KEXEC=y
CONFIG_KEXEC_FILE=y

Any suggestions ?
